# how to get the content of QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use `QLineEdit` for input. My problem is that I don't know how I can read its contents.

Let's say I have:

```
QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit("");
```

After adding it to the GUI how can get the content? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you even looked at the docs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has a `text` property, so simply do:

```
edit->text();
```

Comment: I used it but itdidn't work so I thought it's not the right function

Comment: @Engine You should have mentioned that in the question, then. And elaborated on how it "didn't work."

Comment: the content will be saved after hitting Enter button or automaticly ?

Comment: AFAIK, this property is dynamic. That is, it should return the current content at the time of call.